# Extracting few files without scanning whole tar.gz

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I would like to extract few files from one directory in tar.gz. The problem is that in the location I find a lot of files and the process of unpacking the whole folder is inefficient. I tried to extract them individually, but before extracting a particular file it scans the entire package. Is there a way to skip a scan and extract directly?

script for extracting a single file one by one:

```
filesList=( "file1" "file2" "file3"  )
filesPath="path/to/files/inside/targz/"
for i in "${filesList[@]}"
do
    tar -xvf compressed.tar.gz $filesPath$i
done
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61461/how-to-extract-specific-files-from-tar-gz

Comment: To extract a tar.gz (not tar) add option `-z`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a specific file from tar you can use:

```
tar -zxvf <tar_name> <file_to_untar>
```

Comment: What exactly changes the "filter the archive through gzip" option, I mean -z?

Comment: @Jyoti: to extract a tar (not tar.gz) remove `-z`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to unserdstand what is the scan (maybe in another part of the script). The for loop can be avoided and tar called once.

```
tar -xvf compressed.tar.gz "${filesList[@]/#/$filesPath}"
```

or process the list first

```
filesList=( "file1" "file2" "file3"  )
filesPath="path/to/files/inside/targz/"
filesPathList=()
for i in "${filesList[@]}"
do
    filesPathList+=("$filesPath$i")
done
tar -xvf compressed.tar.gz "${filesPathList[@]}"
```

I've just seen it's a tar.gz, so inflated (`gzip -cd` or `zcat`) inside the loop. Which explain the poor performance, another option can be to gunzip first.

Comment: By saying scan I mean that the process of unpacking a single folder continues the same as extracting the whole package. With the difference that in the case of the whole it prints all the paths (instead of selected). 
tar on array its really good idea. I didn't know I can use "tar" this way. Anyway it still would "look for" the paths.
It's possible that I'm tottaly misunderstanding extracting process :D

Comment: To extract a tar.gz (not tar) add option `-z`.

Comment: @Cyrus in fact it depends on versions of tar it can work without `z`, i've just tested it and it works (gnu tar 1.29). I would also write without `-` as `xvf` or `tf` are arguments not options, but I let it like in the question.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: Interesting. Thank you for the information.

Comment: more exactly they are options and it's the old syntax, I'm more familiar with.